# Call custom-domain REST-Enabled SQL Service from APEX Developer Service

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex, acl, oracle-ords

My production app is an APEX application already running in a custom domain (mydomain.com). I've already configured REST-enabled SQL Service, and connected to it successfully from another APEX installation on anther custom domain of mine. So that seems fine.

Now, I've spun up a new APEX Developer Service environment on oraclecloud, and I'm trying to create a REST-enabled SQL Service reference to point to the mydomain.com instance. I'm getting the typical error that says the endpoint does not point to a REST-enabled SQL Service.

In the past, when I've had this problem, I solved it by:

- Creating an ACL for the remote domain, which allows responses to come back into the requester, and
- Modifying the wallet on the requester to include the root CA certificate of the remote domain. This is needed because my custom remote instance is running HTTPS.

As far as I know, both of those require database and/or filesystem access, which I don't have in the APEX Developer Service environment on oraclecloud.

So, my question is: is it possible to do this and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

you might execute the following in SQL Commands in order to test networking connectivity between the APEX service and your APEX instance within (yourdomain.com).

```
declare
    l_result clob;
begin
    l_result := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
                    p_url =>         'http://server.yourdomain.com/path/to/restenabledsql/_/sql',
                    p_http_method => 'GET' );
    htp.p( 'Status: ' || apex_web_service.g_status_code );
end;
```

As this block does not pass credentials, it will never work correctly. However, based on the thrown error message, we will hopefully get a better indication about the actual cause.

Comment: The result:

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1182
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 782
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1209
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 756
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1023
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1371
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 626
ORA-06512: at line 4
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Comment: Based on the error stack, APEX attempts to set a proxy server for making the request, which is not allowed on Autonomous Database or the APEX service. So you might double-check the application as well as the INTERNAL workspace, and clear out all defined proxy servers.

Comment: This is a brand new environment we provisioned on OracleCloud this week, so we didn't do anything fancy like proxies, etc and we haven't even loaded our app on it as yet @Carsten

Comment: hmmm .. that is odd. From the remote, and without looking into this in detail, I'm afraid I don't have more tips. Just one thought; the URL you're calling _is_ a HTTPS URL and it uses a certificate which is signed by a public CA, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's from digicert. On another custom installation I have, I've successfully created wallets to include the root cert so that this same kind of connection will work.

Comment: So, on ADB you cannot create the wallets yourself; this is centrally managed. You'd need to file a service request for this ...

Comment: thanks for all your help on this and my previous APEX questions. We will raise this with Oracle support as you suggested.